# C# winform Application Webview2 webBrowser Submit button Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, webview2

I am New in the c# webview2 browser
I need click continue button but when I am using my code then it's not working totally.

```
<button id="reg-submit-button" name="signup" type="submit" data-rapid-tracking="true" data-ylk="elm:btn;elmt:nxt;slk:continue;mKey:registration-continue" class="pure-button puree-button-primary puree-spinner-button">Continue</button>
```

Please check this & give me better solution.

Below I am trying but not success.

```
            webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("Document.GetElementById('reg-submit-button').submit();");
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, you've made some mistakes in your JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById your also calling submit() instead of click(). You'd call submit() if you had a form reference.

Comment: You invoke `submit()` on `<form>` object, not `<input>`. See [HTMLFormElement.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit). Also see [button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>
        function btnClickAction(name) {
            alert('button ' + name + ' was clicked');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button1" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button1')">Click Me 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button2" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button2')">Click Me 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button3" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button3')" value="Click Me 3">Click Me 3</button>

    <input type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button4" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button4')" value="Click Me 4" />

</body>
</html>
```

Try the following:

```
await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('reg-submit-button').click();");
```

Below shows how to create a function that you can call which can be useful for debugging.

```
string jsCode = "function clickDesiredButtonById(btnId) {
    let result = null;
    let desiredButton = document.getElementById(btnId);
    
    if (desiredButton) {
        desiredButton.click();
        result = 'button with id = ' + btnId + ' clicked';
    }
    
    //window.chrome.webview.postMessage("result:" + result);
    return result;
}";

jsCode += System.Environment.NewLine;
jsCode += "clickDesiredButtonById('" + btnId + "');";

var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsCode);
```

**Note**: `btnId` is the id of your desired button.

Feel free to use another method of putting the code into a string.