# WebView2 (WPF) - Load website from local folder and call C# Function and call JS Function

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, function, webview2

I am making a WPF application use WebView2.

There will be an installer that will installer the WPF application in a folder and will also download and write the website into a subfolder of the installation directory. Such as this:

```
Installation Directory
├───Website
│   ├───index.css
│   └───index.html
└───WPF Self Contained EXE
```

The WebView2 will load the website using this (I think): `webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Website");`

This should load `index.html` and all the files it references such as `index.css`.

Now my main concern is that how do I call a JavaScript function from C#. So far after googling I have only found ways for WebView1. And I couldn't find anything about calling a C# method from JavaScript.

So three things:

1. Is this `webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Website");` correct for loading a website from a local folder?
2. How would I call a JavaScript function and pass an C# object to it from a C# method.
3. How would I call a C# function from the JavaScript script?

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The following should help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578936/javascript-scripts-in-html-not-firing-from-winform-webbrowser-control/68592056#68592056, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452473/how-to-click-button-in-c-sharp-webview/65470588#65470588, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350635/c-sharp-winform-application-webview2-webbrowser-submit-button-not-working/68353911#68353911 . However, rather than storing the files (.html and .css) as embedded resources (as shown in those posts), store them as files on disk-as you already planned to do.

Comment: Thanks! This helps! I think that the storing the files on disk will make updating faster as they will probably be updated faster than the actual app... Thanks again!

Comment: The following may be helpful for how to call a C# function from JavaScript: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/335

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using file URI

I'm not sure if AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory will always get you the correct path. You can use something like the following:

```
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
string websiteFolder = Path.Combine(exeFolder, "website");
string htmlPath = Path.Combine(websiteFolder, "index.html");

webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(htmlPath);
```

You must include the path to the index.html itself and not just the folder containing the index.html.

Normally Navigate should take a URI, but if you provide a Windows file path instead it will convert it to a file URI for you and should work.

File URIs have some limitations when trying to incorporate http(s) URIs and other web platform features that require https.

### Using a virtual HTTPS URI

If you hit issues using file URIs you can use [CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping) to map a Windows file path to a fake HTTPS hostname:

```
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
string websiteFolder = Path.Combine(exeFolder, "website");

webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping("appassets.example", websiteFolder, CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors);
webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://appassets.example/index.html");
```

This will make a fake hostname 'appassets.example' that will map to your Windows file path. And since its HTTPS URIs you don't hit the same issues as you do with file URIs.

### Host objects in script

For your questions 2 & 3 you can use [CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addhostobjecttoscript). The current implementation of AddHostObjectToScript requires your C# classes to be specially marked. You can see it in the AddHostObjectToScript documentation.

Comment: Hi. The local website works! Thanks! When I call a c# method inside a class that returns a List<MyOwnClassName>, I get null. This is my js code: `const transaction = chrome.webview.hostObjects.transaction; transaction.GetReceiptItems(10).then(TResult1 => {this.amount = TResult1.Count;});`

Comment: This logs an error to the console: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Count' of null` Note I am using react.js.

Comment: Is the type of the result of GetReceiptItems also marked with the appropriate attributes `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` and `[ComVisible(true)]`?

Comment: The JavaScript code on the MS website is incorrect. `const transaction = chrome.webview.hostObjects.transaction;` needs to have `await`. It should be `const transaction = await chrome.webview.hostObjects.transaction;`

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Let me try the new code. The result is a List<T>... Do you mean the <T> class?

Comment: Thanks! So far everything works! If I get stuck later on I will ask you! Thanks again!